# How to handle Next and Previous button in AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayerviewcontroller

In my app i have used `AVPlayerViewController` to play audio file using URL.Now i want to handle **Next** and **Previous** button click event in `AVPlayerViewController`.

Here is code which i have tried :

```
func playSound(_ url: URL) {
    let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    let player = AVPlayerViewController()
    player.player = avPlayer
    avPlayer.play()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.donePlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)//NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime
    self.present(player, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

 self.playSound("Here your URL")
```

If any one know thenPlease let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

check this demo project:[project demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-hmxrLGwM6zTm4wYS14aWcxOEU/view)

where it is shown how to put a custom buttons on top of AVPlayer and they responds to clicks.

What was done:

Xib (uses auto layout) file created which hold custom buttons like next, replay and others.
Buttons were connected to the source which prints what needs to do. Like: play next or replay.
Was added observer which observe when video is finished to play.
When video is finished to play xib file with buttons will be shown.

Comment: Not handling the next previous button and its old swift code.